# What is the undotted sermon of Imam Ali (a.s.)?

Tags: source-identification, ali, khutbah

There is an undotted sermon which is attributed to Imam Ali (a.s.). It is said that this is without any dot. Is it right?
If so, can you present its text?

Answer (score 7):

**Yeah, imam Ali(a.s.) has an undotted sermon, it is as follow:**

### *الْحَمْدُ للَّهِ أَهْلِ الْحَمْدِ وَ مَأْوَاهُ، وَ لَهُ أَوْکدُ الْحَمْدِ وَ أَحْلَاهُ، وَ أسعَدُ أَسْرَعُ*

### الْحَمْدِ وَ أَسْرَاهُ، وَ أَطْهَرُ الْحَمْدِ وَ أَسْمَاهُ، وَ أَکرَمُ الْحَمْدِ وَ أَوْلَاهُ. الْوَاحِدِ الأَحَدِ الصَّمَدِ، لَا وَالِدَ لَهُ وَ لَا وَلَدَ . سَلَّطَ الْمُلُوک وَ أَعْدَاهَا، وَ أَهْلَک الْعُدَاةَ وَ أَدْحَاهَا، وَ أَوْصَلَ الْمَکارِمَ وَ أَسْرَاهَا. وَ سَمَک السَّمَاءَ وَ عَلَّاهَا، وَ سَطَحَ الْمِهَادَ وَ طَحَاهَا، وَ وَطَّدَهَا وَ دَحَاهَا، وَ مَدَّهَا وَ سَوَّاهَا، وَ مَهَّدَهَا وَ وَطَّاهَا، وَ أَعْطَاکمْ مَاءَهَا وَ مَرْعَاهَا، وَ أَحْکمَ عَدَدَ الأُمَمِ وَ أَحْصَاهَا، وَ عَدَّلَ الأَعْلَامَ وَ أَرْسَاهَا. أَلَا لَهُ الأَوَّلُ لَا مُعَادِلَ لَهُ، وَ لَا رَادَّ لِحُکمِهِ. لَا إِلهَ إِلَّا هُوَ الْمَلِک السَّلَامُ الْمُصَوِّرُ الْعَلَّامُ، الْحَاکمُ، الْوَدُودُ، الْمُطَهِّرُ، الطَّاهِرُ، الْمَحْمُودُ أَمْرُهُ، الْمَعْمُورُ حَرَمُهُ، الْمَأْمُولُ کرَمُهُ. عَلَّمَکمْ کلَامَهُ، وَ أَرَاکمْ أَعْلَامَهُ، وَ حَصَّلَ لَکمْ أَحْکامَهُ، وَ حَلَّلَ حَلَالَهُ، وَ حَرَّمَ حَرَامَهُ. وَ حَمَّلَ مُحَمَّداً الرِّسَالَةَ، رَسُولَهُ الْمُکرَّمُ، الْمُسَوَّدُ الْمُسَدَّدِ، الطُّهْرُ الْمُطَهَّرُ. أَسْعَدَ اللَّهُ الأُمَّةَ لِعُلُوِّ مَحَلِّهِ، وَ سُمُوِّ سُؤْدَدِهِ، وَ سَدَادِ أَمْرِهِ، وَ کمَالِ مُرَادِهِ. أَطْهَرُ وُلْدِ آدَمَ مَوْلُوداً، وَ أَسْطَعُهُمْ سُعُوداً، وَ أَطْوَلُهُمْ عَمُوداً، وَ أَرْوَاهُمْ عُوداً، وَ أَصَحُّهُمْ عُهُوداً، وَ أَکرَمُهُمْ مُرْداً وَ کهُولاً. صَلَاةُ اللَّهِ لَهُ وَ لآلِهِ الأَطْهَارِ، مُسَلَّمَةً وَ مُکرَّرَةً مَعْدُودَةً، وَ لآلِ وُدِّهِمُ الْکرَامِ مُحَصَّلَةً مْرَدَّدَةً، مَا دَامَ لِلسَّمَاءِ أَمْرٌ مَرْسُومٌ، وَ حَدُّ مَعْلُومٌ. أَرْسَلَهُ رَحْمَةً لَکمْ، وَ طَهَارَةً لأَعْمَالِکمْ، وَ هُدُوءِ دَارِکمْ، وَ دُحُورِ عَارِکمْ، وَ صَلَاحِ أَحْوَالِکمْ، وَ طَاعَةً للَّهِ وَ رُسُلِهِ، وَ عِصْمَةً لَکمْ وَ رَحْمَةً. إِسْمَعُوا لَهُ، وَ رَاعُوا أَمْرَهُ، وَ حَلِّلُوا مَا حَلَّلَ، وَ حَرِّمُوا مَا حَرَّمَ. وَ اعْمَدُوا، رَحِمَکمُ اللَّهُ، لِدَوَامِ الْعَمَلِ، وَ ادْحَرُوا الْحِرْصَ وَ اعْدِمُوا الْکسَلَ، وَ أدْرُوا السَّلَامَةَ، وَ حِرَاسَةَ الْمُلْک وَ رَوْعَهَا، وَ هَلَعَ الصُّدُورِ وَ حُلُولَ کلِّهَا وَ هَمِّهَا. هَلَک، وَ اللَّهِ، أَهْلُ الإِصْرَارِ، وَ مَا وَلَدَ وَالِدٌ لِلإِسْرَارِ. کمْ مُؤَمِّلٍ أَمَّلَ مَا أَهْلَکهُ، وَ کمْ مَالٍ وَ سِلَاحٍ أُعِدَّ صَارَ لِلأَعْدَاءِ عَدُّهُ وَ عَمَدُهُ. اللَّهُمَّ لَک الْحَمْدُ وَ دَوَامُهُ، وَ الْمُلْک وَ کمَالُهُ. لَا إِلهَ إِلَّا هُوَ، وَسِعَ کلَّ حِلْمٍ حِلْمُهُ، وَ سَدَّدَ کلَّ حُکمٍ حُکمُهُ،وَ حَدَرَ کلَّ عِلْمٍ عِلْمُهُ. عَصَمَکمْ وَ لَوَّاکمْ، وَ دَوَامَ السَّلَامَةِ أَوْلَاکمْ،وَ لِلطَّاعَةِ سَدَّدَکمْ،وَ لِلإِسْلَامِ هَدَاکمْ،وَ رَحِمَکمْ وَ سَمِعَ دُعَاءَکمْ،وَ طَهَّرَ أَعْمَالَکمْ،وَ أَصْلَحَ أَحْوَالَکمْ.وَ أَسْأَلُهُ لَکمْ دَوَامَ السَّلَامَةِ،وَ کمَالَ السَّعَادَةِ، وَ الآلَاءَ الدَّارَّةِ،وَ الأَحْوَالَ السَّارَّةِ. وَ الْحَمْدُ للَّهِ وَحْدَه

محمودى، محمد باقر، نهج ‏السعادة فی ‏مستدرک ‏نهج ‏البلاغة، مصحح: آل‏ طالب، عزیز، ج 1، ص 109111

(Mahmudi, Mohammad Baqer, Nahjo Sa’adah fi Mostadrak Nahjol-balaghah, editor: Ale-Taleb, Aziz, vol. 1, P. 109-111. (Notice, The first line of the mentioned sermon is from another source).

---

**To see the English translation of imam Ali’s undotted sermon(according to another narration), you can refer to the following link:**

[www.al-islam.org/sermon-imam-ali-without-any-arabic-letter-contains-dots-imam-ali-ibn-abu-talib](http://www.al-islam.org/articles/sermon-imam-ali-without-any-arabic-letter-contains-dots-imam-ali-ibn-abu-talib)

---

Source:

- [www.islamquest.net](http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa24712)

Comment: can you add the translation of this sermon here? because most of users here are english.

Comment: Dear Battle of Karbala, thank you for your attention. I added its English translation too. To see its English translation, you can refer to the link which is beneath the page.